# "mailx" -r command not working

Tags: unix, solaris, mailx

I am using the below command to a mail from one user to another with an attachment placed as the content

```
mailx -r "sendermail@abc.com" -s "testing" "recievermailid@xyz.com" < emailmessageMail.txt
```

and i am getting the below error message..

```
   mailx: invalid option -- r

   Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...

        [-- sendmail-options ...]

   mail [-iInNv] -f [name]

   mail [-iInNv] [-u user]
```

Can someone please advise.. Thanks in advance

Comment: mailx -V
mailx: invalid option -- V
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user]

Answer (score 2):

Just install

```
sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx
```

bsd-mailx doesn't have this option.
In order to check use this command:

```
dpkg -S $(readlink -e $(which mailx))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your version of `mailx` command doesn't support specifying sender address on command line. Add `From:` header line at the beginning of your `emailmessageMail.txt` file, for example:

```
From: sendermail@abc.com

[Message body]
```

Remember to separate header from body with blank line.

**Update:**

I noticed that it should also honour sendmail options, see `[-- sendmail-options ...]` in usage. So optionally you may try:

```
 mailx -s "testing" "recievermailid@xyz.com" -- -f "sendermail@abc.com" < emailmessageMail.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this error when I used Centos 5, but it is okay for Centos 6 or higher

```
#Cenos 5
mailx -s "subject"  -c "email1" "email2"
```